# Hibernate - duplicate key value violates unique constraint

Tags: hibernate, postgresql, jpa

I have the following problem

```
@Entity
@Table(name="tb_pessoa", schema="public")
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.JOINED)
public class Pessoa implements Serializable {
   private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

   @Id
   @SequenceGenerator(name = "tb_pessoa_id_seq", sequenceName = "tb_pessoa_id_seq", schema="public")
   @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO, generator = "tb_pessoa_id_seq")
   @Column(name = "id", nullable = false)
   private Integer id;

   ...
```

---

```
@Entity  
@Table(name="tb_pessoafisica", schema="public")
@PessoaFisicaAnnotation
@PrimaryKeyJoinColumn(name = "id")
public class PessoaFisica extends Pessoa implements Serializable {
   private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

   @Column(name = "email")
   private String email;

   ...
```

Assuming the **Pessoa** table has records with **id** 1 to 500. When I run the code below:

```
PessoaFisica pessoaFisica = new PessoaFisica();
pessoaFisica.setEmail("teste@123.com");

...

em.persist(pessoa);
```

It's happening the following error:

```
17:26:13,613 ERROR [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper] (http--10.36.1.49-8180-1) ERROR: duplicate key value violates unique constraint "tb_pessoa_pkey"
    Detalhe: Key (id)=(438) already exists.
17:26:13,614 WARN  [com.arjuna.ats.arjuna] (http--10.36.1.49-8180-1) ARJUNA012125: TwoPhaseCoordinator.beforeCompletion - failed for SynchronizationImple< 0:ffff7f000101:-7f6ae4e3:558080ed:4f, org.hibernate.engine.transaction.synchronization.internal.RegisteredSynchronization@331af73a >: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: ERROR: duplicate key value violates unique constraint "tb_pessoa_pkey"
  Detalhe: Key (id)=(438) already exists.
```

why is trying to use the id **438** and not **501**???

Does anyone know what might be happening?

thank you very much

```
CREATE TABLE tb_pessoa
(
    id integer NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT tb_pessoa_pkey PRIMARY KEY (id)
)

CREATE TABLE tb_pessoafisica
(
    email character varying(64) NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT tb_pessoafisica_pkey PRIMARY KEY (id),
    CONSTRAINT fkee8c050f70415778 FOREIGN KEY (id)
        REFERENCES tb_pessoa (id) MATCH SIMPLE
)

CREATE SEQUENCE tb_pessoa_id_seq
  INCREMENT 1
  MINVALUE 1
  MAXVALUE 9223372036854775807
  START 500
  CACHE 1;
```

Log Hibernate:

```
07:50:52,463 INFO  [stdout] (http--10.36.1.49-8180-2) Hibernate: 
07:50:52,463 INFO  [stdout] (http--10.36.1.49-8180-2)     select
07:50:52,464 INFO  [stdout] (http--10.36.1.49-8180-2)         nextval ('public.tb_pessoa_id_seq')
07:50:52,497 INFO  [stdout] (http--10.36.1.49-8180-2) Hibernate: 
07:50:52,498 INFO  [stdout] (http--10.36.1.49-8180-2)     insert 
07:50:52,499 INFO  [stdout] (http--10.36.1.49-8180-2)     into
07:50:52,499 INFO  [stdout] (http--10.36.1.49-8180-2)         public.tb_pessoa
07:50:52,500 INFO  [stdout] (http--10.36.1.49-8180-2)         (id) 
07:50:52,500 INFO  [stdout] (http--10.36.1.49-8180-2)     values
07:50:52,501 INFO  [stdout] (http--10.36.1.49-8180-2)         (?)
07:50:52,519 WARN  [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper] (http--10.36.1.49-8180-2) SQL Error: 0, SQLState: 23505
07:50:52,521 ERROR [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper] (http--10.36.1.49-8180-2) ERROR: duplicate key value violates unique constraint "tb_pessoa_pkey"
    Detalhe: Key (id)=(438) already exists.
```

Comment: Is there a specific reason you didn't use a `serial` and tell Hibernate that the ID is auto-generated?

Comment: What is your sequence is showing before persisting? It may not start from 500. Should you check it from database?

Comment: Add the hibernate log now... tks.

Comment: resolved with `allocationSize = 1` ... Tks

Answer (score -1):

If you are persisting new entity, what about trying to set `ID` to `null`.

```
PessoaFisica pessoaFisica = new PessoaFisica();
pessoaFisica.setID(null);
pessoaFisica.setEmail("teste@123.com");

...

em.persist(pessoa);
```

This will ensure that the object is new when hibernate trying to persist it.

Comment: Its already new. Its not managed. What is the purpose of setting null to ID?

Comment: If a `null` or `0` zero value is set to ID, then hibernate assume it as a new object.

Comment: I already know that. Since its a new object (`new PeassoaFisica();`) by default its `null`. Nothing will change if you assign `null` to `ID` again and again.

Comment: Nothing yet.. :(... Tks